# How do I weatherize after removing old deck?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

Good morning everyone!

Long time reader first post. I hope you all can give me some insight so I can stop worrying about this project. As you can see from the picture I removed a wood deck from the area. You can still see the ledger board which I believe is installed incorrectly. I am going to remove that board and then I want to install vinyl siding to weatherize the area for the winter (next spring I am going to build a patio and then have someone come out to build the steps down to it). 
My question is: Do I need to install some sort of vapor barrier before I install the vinyl siding? If so what type of product do I need and where/how do I tie it in with whatever is below the rest of the vinyl siding? I peaked under the siding to the left and it doesn’t look like there is any type of vapor barrier under the places already covered by siding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would install a vapor barrier. You can use house wrap such as Tyvek or roof felt paper.  Make sure that the top piece overlaps the bottom piece.  Vinyl siding is easy to remove and replace so you can remove a few pieces, just keep them in order, so you can lap the wrap correctly. There is a tool that helps with removing and replacing the siding.